# Infinite auto scrolling image

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I want to make an auto scrolling image. Here is what I've tried.

[Scrolling image](https://jsfiddle.net/Thura/2260zux5/)

Here is my code.

```
<style> 
   .scroll_container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        /* background-color: #ddd; */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .ads_box_holder {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        min-width:100%; 
        width: auto !important; 
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ads_box {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 190px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .ads_box img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        animation: slide 20s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        0%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
        10%{ transform:translateX(-200px) }
        20%{ transform:translateX(-400px) }
        30%{ transform:translateX(-600px) }
        40%{ transform:translateX(-800px) }
        50%{ transform:translateX(-1000px) }
        60%{ transform:translateX(-1200px) }
        70%{ transform:translateX(-1400px) }
        80%{ transform:translateX(-1600px) }
        90%{ transform:translateX(-1800px) }
        100%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
    }
<style>
<div class="scroll_container">
    <div class="ads_box_holder">
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/ads.png"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/blur.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/foot.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/body.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/s.png"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/menu.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/face.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/c.jpeg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/foot2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="ads_box"><img src="images/b.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I used `keyframe` css. So, when images move to left one after another, there has empty space in the right side as shown in below

```
---------
|       |
| image |  empty space are left here
|       |
---------
```

In the reality, I want to add my images dynamically and images may be over 20 images. So, I'm not sure this `keyframes` is ok or not when images add dynamically.

I want to replace that empty space to the all of the images inside this box.
So, there is no empty space left and images are always scroll one after another.
But, I don't know how to replace images when space found inside `ads_box_holder` div.

And I remove css animation and also tried with javascript like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var childCount = $(".ads_box_holder :visible").children().length;
    var move = 0;
    var hideImageTime = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
        hideImageTime += 1;
        move += 200;
        $(".ads_box_holder").css({
            "margin-left":-move+"px",
        });
        if(hideImageTime > childCount) {
            jQuery('.ads_box_holder .ads_box').each(function(){
                var next = jQuery(this).next();
                count += 1;
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = jQuery(this).siblings(':first');
                }
                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo(jQuery(this));
            });
        }
    },2000);
});
</script>
```

But it is the same result when I use `keyframe` css.

NOTE: The image moving style is ok but I just want to place all images when empty space found inside `ads_box_holder`.

I have no idea how to achieve what I want. I'm really appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: So you want to repeat this images in loop? or after last image it will scroll directly tot the 1st image and then start scrolling?

Comment: @SagarKodte Yes, after last image it will scroll directly to first, second, third images etc.

img 9 | img 10| img 1| img 2| etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got what I want. Clone first child and append at last of `ads_box_holder` and remove first child.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        function animation() {
            $('.ads_box_holder').children(':first').clone().appendTo(".ads_box_holder");
            $('.ads_box_holder').children(':first').css({
                "margin-left":"-204px",
                "-webkit-transition": "all 0.7s ease-out",
                   "-moz-transition": "all 0.7s ease-out",
                    "-ms-transition": "all 0.7s ease-out",
                     "-o-transition": "all 0.7s ease-out",
                        "transition": "all 0.7s ease-out"
            });
            setTimeout(function(){$('.ads_box_holder').children(':first').remove()},1500);
        }
        window.setInterval(animation,2000);
});
```

I hope it will help for someone.